# Which Android devices support jni?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, java-native-interface, equinox

I have developed an Android application which uses JNI (**java native interface**) for Archos 43.

Had no problems and i was able to run the application smoothly. 
Later I tried to run the same application on **Samsung I9100G Galaxy S II** as well as **Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II**.

I was able to run the application on **I9100G** but not on **I9100**.

> The reason being that the JNI part of the application was not supported on I9100.

I did try to get to know the reason for this and was able to  find that I9100G uses `Ti OMAP 4430 chipset` and `PowerVR SGX540 as GPU whereas I9100 uses Exynos 4210 chipset and Mali-400MP as GPU.`

I suspect that the reason might be the change in chipset (since Archos 43 uses Ti OMAP as well). But any further results couldn't be obtained from my search.

**update** The application makes use of bluetooth. While trying to connect to a custom hardware(CH), am not able to get any response from the CH when am running the application on I9100. The bluetooth communication part is written using jni.

So my question is whether am not able to run my application with JNI on **I9100** because of the chipset and if so why ?

Also a more general question is which devices support Android JNI applications and what are the basic features necessary in a device to run an Android JNI application ? 
(I spent a considerable amount of my time trying to find the answers for all these questions and any help will be greatly appreciated.)

Thank You.

Comment: I have been working on an application which uses JNI and have been using Samsung Galaxy S-2 GT-I9100 (with Android 4.0.3) for testing without any problem.

Comment: What is the role of jni in the application ?

Comment: Crawling and indexing some data

Comment: I guess it could depend on the processor architecture rather than Jni support. For example arm vs arm-v7 or neon or other extensions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Android devices 'support' JNI, that is how a big part of the OS is implemented: Java services and frameworks using native libraries via JNI. There are, however, different architectures, and if you have a native module, you need to make sure you build one for each architecture you want to support. Even if you are targeting ARM devices only, there are ARMv5 and ARMv7 ones out there. ARMv5 should work on all, but is slower.

Galaxy SII devices probably use the same architecture, so you've hit some other problem/bug. What errors did you get? Post logcat if available. Maybe you are trying to access hardware that is not available on one of the devices? Or link against system libraries that are for some reason missing?

Comment: The application makes use of bluetooth. While trying to connect to a custom hardware(CH), am not able to get any response from the CH when am running the application on I9100. The bluetooth communication part is written using jni.

Comment: Then you should focus on debugging that part first. Might be a driver or Android problem (if the devices are running different versions).

Comment: Both the devices are running android version 2.3.3 and the application doesn't run on devices supporting anything less than ARMv7.

Comment: OK, so you need to find the underlying issue. It most probably is not JNI itself.

Comment: The application part without jni works on any device with andoid version greater than 2.3. It is only the communication part written in jni that can run only on specific devices.

Comment: As I said, you need to find why. It is not because it JNI/native code, it is because of something it does (or doesn't do). Check how it crashes, check if all the needed libraries are in place, take dumps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you disclosed that the problem might be related to BT on 2.3.3, it all makes sense. The Android Bluetooth interface before 4.0 was not standartized, and it's most likely that your code is TI OMAP - specific. So, if you want to support other chipsets, you need to communicate to other drivers, or target devices with ICS and higher.

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to what may be the remedial measure?

Comment: I would download the sources of cyanogen for I9100 and find the way they communicate with Bluetooth.